# SSAS Tabular deployment issue

Tags: sql-server, deployment, ssas, data-analysis

When copying files from an SSAS project and attempting to deploy them, complications arise if the file paths have been altered. How should this issue be addressed?

If the original file in this path

```
c:/projects/orignalproject
```

and I take a copy from it to the new path

```
c:/newproject/orignalproject_copy
```

I get this error:

> the deployment failed

I tried rebuild the project and deploy again the deployment failed.